# Can the addition of two spacelike vectors ever null?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, causality

Consider $A^\mu = (a,b)$ and $B^\mu = (c,d)$ where $a<b$ and $c<d$ making them spacelike vectors with a metric of $\text{diag}(1,-1)$. Then, $A^\mu + B^\mu = (a+c,b+d)\equiv C^\mu$. For a vector to be null, $C^\mu C_\mu = 0 \implies (a+c)^2 - (b+d)^2 = 0$. I am trying to find a condition when this is true, but all I can find is that this can never be null since the above equation implies $a+c = b+d$ but $a+c < b+d$ which is a contradiction to the above assumption.

Is this "proof" correct?

Comment: What you can't do is add two future-directed timelike vectors (i.e. both in the same light cone) to make a null vector. All other combinations work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A^\mu=(1,100)$ and let $B^\mu=(0,-99)$ which are both spacelike then $A^\mu+B^\mu=(1,1)$ which is null. The issue is your conditions for being spacelike are wrong.

Answer (score 4):

$a<b$ is not the right condition to make $A=(a,b)$ spacelike.  Instead, we should have $\eta(A,A) = a^2-b^2 <0$, which neither implies nor is implied by $a<b$.

> Can the addition of two spacelike vectors ever be null?

Sure - if $A$ is spacelike, then $-A$ is also spacelike, and $A+(-A)=0$ which is certainly null.